# want to recreate my asp.net code in my sql

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

I currently have an asp.net page, that takes in the data from this view and based on the percentage it will change the text of an amount field. Meaning that if a user reaches a certain percentage they get a certain incentive amount.

However, I am currently doing this in my program however, for reporting purposes i want to be able to do this straight directly in sql, and not in my asp.net page.

> what i am trying to do is almost
>   something like if percentage column =
>   65 to 70 percent then amount column =
>   50 if percentage column = 70 to 75
>   percent then amount column = 75
>
> straight in my dataview and not in my
>   asp.net page

```
If Decimal.Parse(percent.Text) >= 0.65 And percent.Text < 0.7 Then
                Amount.Text = 50
            ElseIf Decimal.Parse(percent.Text) >= 0.7 And percent.Text < 0.75 Then
                Amount.Text = 75
            ElseIf Decimal.Parse(percent.Text) >= 0.75 And percent.Text < 0.8 Then
                Amount.Text = 200
            ElseIf Decimal.Parse(percent.Text) >= 0.8 And percent.Text < 0.85 Then
                Amount.Text = 500
            ElseIf Decimal.Parse(percent.Text) >= 0.85 And percent.Text < 0.9 Then
                Amount.Text = 625
            ElseIf Decimal.Parse(percent.Text) >= 0.9 And percent.Text < 0.95 Then
                Amount.Text = 750
            ElseIf Decimal.Parse(percent.Text) >= 0.95 And percent.Text < 1.0 Then
                Amount.Text = 1000
```

Here is my view query, i almost want to add an if statement but im not sure if it is the best way of doing this.

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT SUM(yes) AS Countreported, SUM(no) AS Countnotreported, SUM(yes) + SUM(no) AS count, BMM, BYYYY, userid, SUM(pax) 
                          AS party, CAST(SUM(yes) AS decimal(4, 1)) / (SUM(yes) + SUM(no)) AS percentage
    FROM         (SELECT     SUM(CASE WHEN [insreported] IS NULL THEN 0 WHEN [insreported] = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yes, 
                                                  SUM(CASE WHEN [insreported] IS NULL THEN 1 WHEN [insreported] = 'YES' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS no, CASE WHEN USERID = 'chrisn' OR
                                                  USERID = 'CHRISN' THEN 'chrism' ELSE USERID END AS userid, dbo.agent_insurance_incentive_data.BMM, 
                                                  dbo.agent_insurance_incentive_data.BYYYY, SUM(dbo.agent_insurance_incentive_data.PARTY) AS pax, 
                                                  dbo.incentive_agents.department
                           FROM          dbo.agent_insurance_incentive_data LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                  dbo.incentive_agents ON dbo.agent_insurance_incentive_data.USERID = dbo.incentive_agents.agent
                           WHERE      (dbo.agent_insurance_incentive_data.DYYYY >= '2009') AND (dbo.agent_insurance_incentive_data.BYYYY > 2008)
                           GROUP BY dbo.agent_insurance_incentive_data.USERID, dbo.agent_insurance_incentive_data.BMM, dbo.agent_insurance_incentive_data.BYYYY, 
                                                  dbo.agent_insurance_incentive_data.DMM, dbo.agent_insurance_incentive_data.DYYYY, dbo.incentive_agents.department) 
                          AS derived
    WHERE     (userid IN
                              (SELECT     agent
                                FROM          dbo.incentive_agents AS incentive_agents_1)) OR
                          (userid = 'chrisn')
    GROUP BY BMM, BYYYY, userid
    ORDER BY userid, BYYYY, BMM
```

Comment: sorry, about that i went back and accepeted the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually this should be fairly simple. Just adopt the following formula to your query.

```
Declare @Tmp Table(
    Percentage float 
)

Insert Into @Tmp Values (.65)
Insert Into @Tmp Values (.7)
Insert Into @Tmp Values (.75)
Insert Into @Tmp Values (.8)
Insert Into @Tmp Values (.85)
Insert Into @Tmp Values (.9)
Insert Into @Tmp Values (.95)

SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN Percentage >= .65 AND Percentage < .7 THEN 50
        WHEN Percentage >= .7 AND Percentage < .75 THEN 75
        WHEN Percentage >= .75 AND Percentage < .8 THEN 200
        WHEN Percentage >= .8 AND Percentage < .85 THEN 500
        WHEN Percentage >= .85 AND Percentage < .9 THEN 625
        WHEN Percentage >= .9 AND Percentage < .95 THEN 750
        WHEN Percentage >= .95 AND Percentage < 1 THEN 1000
    END AS Amount,
    Percentage
FROM 
    @Tmp
```

**EDIT:**

Since I can't (don't have the time) to re-create your tables & data.

Shouldn't you be able to do something like:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN Percentage >= .65 AND Percentage < .7 THEN 50
        WHEN Percentage >= .7 AND Percentage < .75 THEN 75
        WHEN Percentage >= .75 AND Percentage < .8 THEN 200
        WHEN Percentage >= .8 AND Percentage < .85 THEN 500
        WHEN Percentage >= .85 AND Percentage < .9 THEN 625
        WHEN Percentage >= .9 AND Percentage < .95 THEN 750
        WHEN Percentage >= .95 AND Percentage < 1 THEN 1000
    END AS Amount,
    *   
FROM 
(
    --Insert your query here
)Tmp2

--OR IF SQL doesn't like the GroupBy/OrderBy statements in the Sub Select 

Declare @Tmp3 Table(
    Countreported float,
    Countnotreported float,
    [count] float,
    BMM float,
    BYYYY float,
    userid int, 
    party int, 
    percentage decimal
)

INSERT INTO @Tmp3
    --Insert your query here

SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN Percentage >= .65 AND Percentage < .7 THEN 50
        WHEN Percentage >= .7 AND Percentage < .75 THEN 75
        WHEN Percentage >= .75 AND Percentage < .8 THEN 200
        WHEN Percentage >= .8 AND Percentage < .85 THEN 500
        WHEN Percentage >= .85 AND Percentage < .9 THEN 625
        WHEN Percentage >= .9 AND Percentage < .95 THEN 750
        WHEN Percentage >= .95 AND Percentage < 1 THEN 1000
    END AS Amount,
    *   
FROM 
    @Tmp3
```

Comment: hmm im having issues adding this method to my query